# how to get start and end index of selection in multiline textbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a textbox and I want to know the start and end index of the value, user had selected/Highlighted.

`like,**here is** my textbox and its is some kind of data in the textbox.`

and the bold "here is" is being selected by user. so, I want the index value of h and s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The starting index can be retrieved from the property `TextBox.SelectionStart`.  The ending index value can be calculated as `TextBox.SelectionStart` + `TextBox.SelectionLength`.

```
int selectionIndexStart = textBox1.SelectionStart;
int selectionIndexEnd = textBox1.SelectionStart + textBox1.SelectionLength;
```

Where `textBox1` is of type `TextBox`.